# Javascript OOP, functions

Tags: javascript, oop, function, addchild

I am attempting to make a HTML5/JavaScript game with EnchantJS which involves a 6x6 grid of colored squares. I got 1 image to show but rather than having 36x4 lines of code to display all of the images i wanted to move it all to a function. The code breaks at line 62 `this.addChild(block);`. I can't seem to figure out why this is not working. I've spent the past days reading up on what functions are and how to call info between functions. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I can't find answers from searching. I come from a purely Java and c++ background so I think I'm messing up the syntax and not understanding something.

```
enchant();

window.onload = function() {

    /*
     *  Game width and height.
     *  Note: Game scale is half so actual width=width/2 and 
     *  actual heigh it height/2.
     */
    var game = new Game(1280,768);

    /*
     *  Game Preload Vars
     */
    game.preload('res/bg2x.png',
     'res/block.png');

    game.fps = 30;
    game.scale = 0.5;

    game.onload = function() {

      console.log("Game Loaded");
      var scene = new SceneGame;
      game.pushScene(scene);

    }

    game.start();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    var SceneGame = Class.create(Scene, {

      initialize: function() {

        var game, bg;
        Scene.apply(this);
        game = Game.instance;

        // Background
        bg = new Sprite(1280,768);
        bg.image = game.assets['res/bg2x.png'];

        // Populate Screen
        this.addChild(bg);

        gridBuilder(500,75);

      }

    });

    var gridBuilder = function(x,y) {

      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;

      block = new Block;
      block.x = x;
      block.y = y;
      this.block = block;

      this.addChild(block); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING.

    };

    var Block = Class.create(Sprite, {

        // The player character.     
        initialize: function() {
         // 1 - Call superclass constructor
         Sprite.apply(this,[100, 100]);
         this.image = Game.instance.assets['res/block.png'];
         // 2 - Animate
         this.animationDuration = 0;
         this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.updateAnimation);
        },

        updateAnimation: function (evt) {        
          this.animationDuration += evt.elapsed * 0.001;       
          if (this.animationDuration >= 0.25) {
              this.frame = (this.frame + 1) % 4;
              this.animationDuration -= 0.25;
          }
        },

    });

}
```

Comment: "Breaks" how? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gridBuilder` is a function, nothing more.  It has no `addChild` method.  The reason `addChild` works in `SceneGame` is because `SceneGame` is created by `Class.create` which I assume has an `addChild` method inherently in it.  Either create `gridBuilder` the same way you create the class `SceneGame` or rethink what you actually want `gridBuilder` to do.  One way or the other, something you're doing isn't adding up and you need to think about what you're actually expecting your JS to accomplish.

Comment: Ok that makes lots of sense. I come from a Java/C++ background so I was misunderstanding what the structure of a .js file is. I fixed my problem by just taking the `this.addChild()` method out of the `gridBuilder`and just made `gridBuilder` return `block` and then added `this.addChild(gridBuilder(500,75))` into SceneGame. Thanks for the explanation @EliGassert!